# Programa para saber cuántas veces se usa las letras del abecedario en cada palabra de un texto

Tags: c++

Intento saber cuántas veces se usan las letras del abecedario en cada palabra de un texto pero por el momento sólo llevo para contar en todo el texto, y me falta contar por cada palabra y poner en qué palabra.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char cad[100];
    int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,i2=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,n2=0,o=0,p=0,q=0,r=0,s=0,t=0,u=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0;

        cout << "Introduzca la cadena: ";
        cin.getline(cad,100);

        int i=0;
        while(cad[i]!='\0'){
        //while(cad[i]!= '\0'){

        if(cad[i]=='a'){
            a++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='b'){
            b++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='c'){
            c++;
        }


        if(cad[i]=='d'){
            d++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='e'){
            e++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='f'){
            f++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='g'){
            g++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='h'){
            h++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='i'){
            i2++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='j'){
            j++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='k'){
            k++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='l'){
            l++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='m'){
            m++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='n'){
            n++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='ñ'){
            n2++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='o'){
            o++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='p'){
            p++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='q'){
            q++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='r'){
            r++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='s'){
            s++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='t'){
            t++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='u'){
            u++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='v'){
            v++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='w'){
            w++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='x'){
            x++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='y'){
            y++;
        }

        if(cad[i]=='z'){
            z++;
        }

            i++;
    }


    if(a!=0)
    cout << "La letra A se uso "<< a << " veces " << endl;
    if(b!=0)
    cout << "La letra B se uso "<< b << " veces " << endl;
    if(c!=0)
    cout << "La letra C se uso "<< c << " veces " << endl;
    if(d!=0)
    cout << "La letra D se uso "<< d << " veces " << endl;
    if(e!=0)
    cout << "La letra E se uso "<< e << " veces " << endl;
    if(f!=0)
    cout << "La letra F se uso "<< f << " veces " << endl;
    if(g!=0)
    cout << "La letra G se uso "<< g << " veces " << endl;
    if(h!=0)
    cout << "La letra H se uso "<< h << " veces " << endl;
    if(i2!=0)
    cout << "La letra I se uso "<< i2 << " veces " << endl;
    if(j!=0)
    cout << "La letra J se uso "<< j << " veces " << endl;
    if(k!=0)
    cout << "La letra K se uso "<< k << " veces " << endl;
    if(l!=0)
    cout << "La letra L se uso "<< l << " veces " << endl;
    if(m!=0)
    cout << "La letra M se uso "<< m << " veces " << endl;
    if(n!=0)
    cout << "La letra N se uso "<< n << " veces " << endl;
    if(n2!=0)
    cout << "La letra Ñ se uso "<< n2 << " veces " << endl;
    if(o!=0)
    cout << "La letra O se uso "<< o << " veces " << endl;
    if(p!=0)
    cout << "La letra P se uso "<< p << " veces " << endl;
    if(q!=0)
    cout << "La letra Q se uso "<< q << " veces " << endl;
    if(r!=0)
    cout << "La letra R se uso "<< r << " veces " << endl;
    if(s!=0)
    cout << "La letra S se uso "<< s << " veces " << endl;
    if(t!=0)
    cout << "La letra T se uso "<< t << " veces " << endl;
    if(u!=0)
    cout << "La letra U se uso "<< u << " veces " << endl;
    if(v!=0)
    cout << "La letra V se uso "<< v << " veces " << endl;
    if(w!=0)
    cout << "La letra W se uso "<< w << " veces " << endl;
    if(x!=0)
    cout << "La letra X se uso "<< x << " veces " << endl;
    if(y!=0)
    cout << "La letra Y se uso "<< y << " veces " << endl;
    if(z!=0)
    cout << "La letra Z se uso "<< z << " veces " << endl;

}
```

Traté de hacer una condicional `while(cad[i]=!' ')` para que tomara en cuenta los espacios que separa palabra por palabra, pero la verdad no encuentro cómo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo pude hacer, aunque con algunos problemas, no soporta minúsculas, y no te dice la cantidad de espacios, sino que te dice la cantidad de palabras. Tampoco usa Ñ, ya que en C y C++ es más complejo ese tema. El problema con eso es que la consola toma los caracteres de diferente forma a como se escriben.

Agregué dos *arrays*, uno para el abecedario y otro para las cantidades, `cants`. Hice uso de `cin` en vez de `cin.getline`, ya que este segundo no lo sé usar. El número 26 hace referencia a la longitud del abecedario inglés, hay que acordárselo de memoria ya que nunca cambia.

Código versión 1: http://cpp.sh/3xmx2

Código versión 2 (muestra cada letra de cada palabra): http://cpp.sh/9ihe

```
#include <iostream> //Librería que no sé lo que hace.
#include <string> //Librería de strings (para usar texto).

using namespace std; //Esto es para usar string, cout, cin...

//Función que recibe un array, pone todos los elementos del array en 0 (cero).
void vaciar(int array[])
{
    //Itera 26 veces
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        //El elemento de la posición i del array lo pone en cero.
        array[i]=0;
    }
}

//Función principal del programa, devuelve un entero de valor cero.
int main()
{
    string cad=""; //Declara cadena vacía.
    string abecedario="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "; //Declara abecedario.
    int cants[26]; //Declara array de 26 enteros con valor cero.
    vaciar(cants); //Llama a la función vaciar y le pasa el array cants.

    //Muestra mensajes.
    cout << "Introduzca la cadena (use la palabra FIN para finalizar): \n";
    cout << "Ejemplo: HOLA MUNDO FIN \n\n";

    //Itera por siempre, ya que true siempre es true (luego aparece un break).
    for(int numPalabra=0;true;numPalabra++)
    {
        vaciar(cants); //Llama a función vaciar.
        cin>>cad; //Pide una palabra.
        if(cad=="FIN"){break;} //Si la palabra es FIN deja de iterar.

        //Itera una palabra, letra por letra.
        for(int i=0;cad[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
            //Itera 26 veces pero en vez de i, con j.
            for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
            {
                //Si la letra del abecedario coincide con la letra de la palabra...
                //Entonces suma 1 a la cantidad de apariciones.
                if(cad[i]==abecedario[j]){cants[j]++;}
            }
        }
        //Muestra el número de la palabra.
        cout<<endl<<"Palabra numero "<<numPalabra<<endl;

        //Itera 26 veces.
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            //Si la cantidad es mayor a cero, entonces...
            if(cants[i]>0)
            {
                //Muestra cantidad de apariciones de la letra...
                //... del abecedario en la posición i.
                cout<<"La letra "<<abecedario[i]<<" se uso "<<cants[i]<<" veces "<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes alguna idea de por ejemplo poner la letra A se uso 2 veces en la palabra 1 o así por ejemplo?

Comment: @OmGaRa6 Se puede, para eso habría que usar una matriz de 2 dimensiones. El array actual es una matriz de una sola dimensión, `cants[26]`, pero no estoy seguro si debería ser `cants[26][100]` o `cants[100][26]`... El 100 es la cantidad de palabras. Es decir, tiene que guardar cada uno de los valores para cada palabra.

Comment: La verdad no entiendo jaja :( también leí sobre hacerlo con código ASCII pero no comprendo como de todos modos gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @OmGaRa6 Ahí modifiqué el código, no fue necesario agregar una matriz, simplemente hice que se renueven los valores, cada vez que aparece una palabra se pone todo en cero... Los caracteres _ASCII_ es fácil, si ponés _ALT+64_ te va a aparecer un arroba, 64 es el número de la letra, si ponés _ALT+100_ sale la letra _d_ en minúscula.

Comment: Orale muy bien oye una pregunta podrías comentar el código para ver que hace cada linea es que soy nuevo en esto y me pierdo,claro si tienes tiempo.

Comment: @OmGaRa6 Listo, código comentado.

Comment: Te agradezco colega ArtEze espero algún día poder colaborarte con algo,saludos desde México, de nuevo gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Aunque la respuesta ya esté como aceptada hay formas más sencillas de llevar el conteo... por ejemplo con un mapa:

**Ejemplo C++11**

```
int main()
{
  std::map<char,int> contador;
  std::string frase;

  std::cout << "Introduzca una frase\n";

  std::getline(std::cin,frase);

  for( char c : frase )
    contador[c]++;

  std::cout << "Resultado:\n";
  for( auto& pair : contador)
  {
      std::cout << pair.first << ":" << pair.second << '\n';
  }
}
```

**Ejemplo C++98**

```
int main()
{
  // Para simplificar la declaración de iteradores
  typedef std::map<char,int> Mapa;

  Mapa contador;
  std::string frase;

  std::cout << "Introduzca una frase\n";

  std::getline(std::cin,frase);

  for( size_t i=0; i<frase.size(); ++i)
    contador[frase[i]]++;

  std::cout << "Resultado:\n";
  for( Mapa::const_iterator it = contador.begin(); it != contador.end(); ++it )
  {
      std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << '\n';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Mi propuesta sería:

1. Separar el texto por palabas.
2. Contar las letras de cada palabra.

Suena sencillo ¿verdad?, veamos cómo lo haría yo:

#### 1. Separar el texto por palabras.

Para separar el texto introducido por palabras, usaría un objeto [`std::stringstream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) para recorrer palabra por palabra y guardarlas en un mapa. Uno de los *problemas* es que las palabras pueden contener símbolos no alfabéticos (signos de puntuación) además de letras en mayúsculas y minúsculas así que debemos *limpiar* cada palabra antes de contarla:

```
std::string limpiar(const std::string &texto)
{
    std::string resultado{};

    for (const auto &letra : texto)
        if (std::isalpha(letra))
            resultado.push_back(std::tolower(letra));

    return resultado;
}
```

Una vez tenemos el código que *limpia* las palabras podemos contarlas:

```
using iterator = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;

std::stringstream input(texto);
std::map<std::string, std::size_t> palabras;
std::size_t recuento_palabras{};

for (iterator begin = iterator{input}, end{}; begin != end; ++begin, ++recuento_palabras)
{
    auto entrada = palabras.insert({limpiar(*begin), 0u});
    ++entrada.first->second;
}

std::cout << "El texto contiene " << recuento_palabras << " palabras.\n";
```

El código anterior recorre el `texto` introducido palabra a palabra mediante el `std::strinstream` llamado `input`. Cada palabra es guardada (tras ser limpiada) en el mapa `palabras` que registra cada una de las palabras y cuantas veces aparece en el texto.

La gracia es que el [`std::map`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) no permite duplicados así que al hacer el `std::map::insert` obtendremos o bien la nueva entrada o bien la entrada previamente introducida, en cuyo caso aumentaríamos el recuento.

#### 2. Contar las letras de cada palabra.

Podemos usar el mismo truco para contar las letras de cada palabra, es decir: usar un `std::map` que guarde las letras y cuantas veces aparecieron:

```
void muestra_letras(const std::string &texto)
{
    std::map<std::string::value_type, std::size_t> letras;
    for (const auto &letra : texto)
    {
        auto recuento = letras.insert({letra, 0u});
        ++recuento.first->second;
    }

    for (const auto &recuento : letras)
        std::cout << '\t' << recuento.first << " = " << recuento.second << '\n';
}
```

#### [El código funcionando](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hZLB4elaIB60atry):

La función `main` tendría este aspecto:

```
int main()
{
    using iterator = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;

    std::stringstream input(texto);
    std::map<std::string, std::size_t> palabras;
    std::size_t recuento_palabras{};

    for (iterator begin = iterator{input}, end{}; begin != end; ++begin, ++recuento_palabras)
    {
        auto entrada = palabras.insert({limpiar(*begin), 0u});
        ++entrada.first->second;
    }

    std::cout << "El texto contiene " << recuento_palabras << " palabras.\n";

    for (const auto &palabra : palabras)
    {
        std::cout << "La palabra '" << palabra.first << "' aparece [" << palabra.second << "] veces en el texto.\n";
        muestra_letras(palabra.first);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Y el resultado de analizar el [Lorem Ipsum](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) sería:

> ```
>    El texto contiene 66 palabras.
>    La palabra 'ad' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       d = 1
>    La palabra 'adipiscing' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       c = 1
>       d = 1
>       g = 1
>       i = 3
>       n = 1
>       p = 1
>       s = 1
>    La palabra 'aliqua' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 2
>       i = 1
>       l = 1
>       q = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'aliquid' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       d = 1
>       i = 2
>       l = 1
>       q = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'amet' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       e = 1
>       m = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'anim' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       i = 1
>       m = 1
>       n = 1
>    La palabra 'aute' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       e = 1
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'cillum' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       c = 1
>       i = 1
>       l = 2
>       m = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'commodi' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       c = 1
>       d = 1
>       i = 1
>       m = 2
>       o = 2
>    La palabra 'consectetur' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       c = 2
>       e = 2
>       n = 1
>       o = 1
>       r = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 2
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'consequat' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       c = 1
>       e = 1
>       n = 1
>       o = 1
>       q = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'culpa' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       c = 1
>       l = 1
>       p = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'cupiditat' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       c = 1
>       d = 1
>       i = 2
>       p = 1
>       t = 2
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'deserunt' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       e = 2
>       n = 1
>       r = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'dolor' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       l = 1
>       o = 2
>       r = 1
>    La palabra 'dolore' aparece [2] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       e = 1
>       l = 1
>       o = 2
>       r = 1
>    La palabra 'ea' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       e = 1
>    La palabra 'eiusmod' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       e = 1
>       i = 1
>       m = 1
>       o = 1
>       s = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'elit' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       i = 1
>       l = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'enim' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       i = 1
>       m = 1
>       n = 1
>    La palabra 'esse' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 2
>       s = 2
>    La palabra 'est' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'et' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'eu' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'ex' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       x = 1
>    La palabra 'excepteur' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       c = 1
>       e = 3
>       p = 1
>       r = 1
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>       x = 1
>    La palabra 'exercitation' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       c = 1
>       e = 2
>       i = 2
>       n = 1
>       o = 1
>       r = 1
>       t = 2
>       x = 1
>    La palabra 'fugiat' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       f = 1
>       g = 1
>       i = 1
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'id' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       i = 1
>    La palabra 'in' aparece [2] veces en el texto.
>       i = 1
>       n = 1
>    La palabra 'incidunt' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       c = 1
>       d = 1
>       i = 2
>       n = 2
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'ipsum' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       i = 1
>       m = 1
>       p = 1
>       s = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'iure' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       i = 1
>       r = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'labore' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       b = 1
>       e = 1
>       l = 1
>       o = 1
>       r = 1
>    La palabra 'laboris' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       b = 1
>       i = 1
>       l = 1
>       o = 1
>       r = 1
>       s = 1
>    La palabra 'laborum' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       b = 1
>       l = 1
>       m = 1
>       o = 1
>       r = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'lorem' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       l = 1
>       m = 1
>       o = 1
>       r = 1
>    La palabra 'magna' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 2
>       g = 1
>       m = 1
>       n = 1
>    La palabra 'minim' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       i = 2
>       m = 2
>       n = 1
>    La palabra 'mollit' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       i = 1
>       l = 2
>       m = 1
>       o = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'nisi' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       i = 2
>       n = 1
>       s = 1
>    La palabra 'non' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       n = 2
>       o = 1
>    La palabra 'nostrud' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       n = 1
>       o = 1
>       r = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'nulla' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       l = 2
>       n = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'obcaecat' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 2
>       b = 1
>       c = 2
>       e = 1
>       o = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'officia' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       c = 1
>       f = 2
>       i = 2
>       o = 1
>    La palabra 'pariatur' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 2
>       i = 1
>       p = 1
>       r = 2
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'proident' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       e = 1
>       i = 1
>       n = 1
>       o = 1
>       p = 1
>       r = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'qui' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       i = 1
>       q = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'quis' aparece [2] veces en el texto.
>       i = 1
>       q = 1
>       s = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'reprehenderit' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       e = 4
>       h = 1
>       i = 1
>       n = 1
>       p = 1
>       r = 3
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'sed' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       d = 1
>       e = 1
>       s = 1
>    La palabra 'sint' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       i = 1
>       n = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'sit' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       i = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'sunt' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       n = 1
>       s = 1
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'tempor' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       m = 1
>       o = 1
>       p = 1
>       r = 1
>       t = 1
>    La palabra 'ullamco' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       c = 1
>       l = 2
>       m = 1
>       o = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'ut' aparece [3] veces en el texto.
>       t = 1
>       u = 1
>    La palabra 'velit' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       e = 1
>       i = 1
>       l = 1
>       t = 1
>       v = 1
>    La palabra 'veniam' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       e = 1
>       i = 1
>       m = 1
>       n = 1
>       v = 1
>    La palabra 'voluptate' aparece [1] veces en el texto.
>       a = 1
>       e = 1
>       l = 1
>       o = 1
>       p = 1
>       t = 2
>       u = 1
>       v = 1
> ```

Comment: Muy elegante y completo

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que C++ se salta el registro de los espacios en blanco (como enter, retroceso, espacio, etc)

[Solucion a tu problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c)

Lo encontre en el SO en ingles, porque tuve el mismo problema con lo de los espacio, como recomendacion usa arrays y bucles for para hacer mas legible y optimo tu codigo

Ej:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   int con=0;
   std::string a;
   std::getline(std::cin,a);
   for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
   {
       if(a[i] == ' ')
          con++;
   }
   std::cout<<"La cantidad de espacios es: "<<con;
   return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a. Contar letras en frase, el programa debe de solicitar como entrada una cadena y una letra, el resultado del programa debe ser el número de veces que aparece la letra en la frase, por ejemplo si la frase es “Buenos dias” y la letra es “s”, entonces el resultado debe de ser 2.

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char frase[100];
    int let_a=0,let_b=0,let_c=0,let_d=0,let_e=0,let_f=0,let_g=0,let_h=0,let_i=0,let_j=0,let_k=0,let_l=0,let_m=0,let_n=0,let_o=0,let_p=0,let_q=0,let_r=0,let_s=0,let_t=0,let_u=0,let_v=0,let_w=0,let_x=0,let_y=0,let_z=0;
    char letra;
    
    cout<<"Escriba una frase: ";
    cin.getline(frase,100,'\n');
    cout<<"Escriba una letra: ";
    cin>>letra;
    
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        switch(frase[i]){
            case 'a':let_a++; break;
            case 'b':let_b++; break;
            case 'c':let_c++; break;
            case 'd':let_d++; break;
            case 'e':let_e++; break;
            case 'f':let_f++; break;
            case 'g':let_g++; break;
            case 'h':let_h++; break;
            case 'i':let_i++; break;
            case 'j':let_j++; break;
            case 'k':let_k++; break;
            case 'l':let_l++; break;
            case 'm':let_m++; break;
            case 'n':let_n++; break;
            case 'o':let_o++; break;
            case 'p':let_p++; break;
            case 'q':let_q++; break;
            case 'r':let_r++; break;
            case 's':let_s++; break;
            case 't':let_t++; break;
            case 'u':let_u++; break;
            case 'v':let_v++; break;
            case 'w':let_w++; break;
            case 'x':let_x++; break;
            case 'y':let_y++; break;
            case 'z':let_z++; break;
        }
    }
    
    switch (letra){
        case 'a': cout<<"Letra a: "<<let_a<<endl; break;
        case 'b': cout<<"Letra b: "<<let_b<<endl; break;
        case 'c': cout<<"Letra c: "<<let_c<<endl; break;
        case 'd': cout<<"Letra d: "<<let_d<<endl; break;
        case 'e': cout<<"Letra e: "<<let_e<<endl; break;
        case 'f': cout<<"Letra f: "<<let_f<<endl; break;
        case 'g': cout<<"Letra g: "<<let_g<<endl; break;
        case 'h': cout<<"Letra h: "<<let_h<<endl; break;
        case 'i': cout<<"Letra i: "<<let_i<<endl; break;
        case 'j': cout<<"Letra j: "<<let_j<<endl; break;
        case 'k': cout<<"Letra k: "<<let_k<<endl; break;
        case 'l': cout<<"Letra l: "<<let_l<<endl; break;
        case 'm': cout<<"Letra m: "<<let_m<<endl; break;
        case 'n': cout<<"Letra n: "<<let_n<<endl; break;
        case 'o': cout<<"Letra o: "<<let_o<<endl; break;
        case 'p': cout<<"Letra p: "<<let_p<<endl; break;
        case 'q': cout<<"Letra q: "<<let_q<<endl; break;
        case 'r': cout<<"Letra r: "<<let_r<<endl; break;
        case 's': cout<<"Letra s: "<<let_s<<endl; break;
        case 't': cout<<"Letra t: "<<let_t<<endl; break;
        case 'u': cout<<"Letra u: "<<let_u<<endl; break;
        case 'v': cout<<"Letra v: "<<let_v<<endl; break;
        case 'w': cout<<"Letra w: "<<let_w<<endl; break;
        case 'x': cout<<"Letra x: "<<let_x<<endl; break;
        case 'y': cout<<"Letra y: "<<let_y<<endl; break;
        case 'z': cout<<"Letra z: "<<let_z<<endl; break;
        
        
    }   

    
    getch();
    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: En estos casos de usan arreglos ...

Answer (score 0):

deberias utilizar una estructura adecuada, por ejemplo puedes modificarlo, en vez de crear 26 variables enteras para todo el abecedario, te crear un array de 26 posiciones y vas incrementando cada ves que encuentres una igualdad

Comment: Creo si tienes razón pero quedaría igual solo contara de todo el texto la intención es saber por ejemplo:  hola mundo h--1 vez - en palabra 1 y así todas las letras.

Comment: @OmGaRa6 si usas una estructura parecida al Map?

Comment: Nunca había escuchada de ella como lo dije en la pregunta pero fue editada soy principiante pero dejame busco, gracias.

Comment: @OmGaRa6 si te sirvió marca como respuesta valida

Comment: Esta respuesta, aunque una excelente recomendación, realmente no responde a la pregunta.